# Best Clusterizing Techninque for 7 points Likert scale

Tags: clustering, references, k-means, likert

What is the best clustering method seven points Likert Scale. When what I am looking to answer is if there are groups of people behavior on it. 
For example. I have around 30 questions with this scale. As I think this is a huge dataset with 30X7 = 210 points for a K-means. Book recommendations are welcome.

Comment: Have you looked at previous questions about clustering Likert type of data?

Comment: Yes, I did and found nothing relevant or close to my question doubts. Please check  my answer to Peter Flom below.

Comment: For example, they will tell you that you should *not* treat Likely items as numeric, and in particular not as linear...

Comment: Thanks Anony. Indeed they will answer that. That it is why I am asking for alternatives for the K-means.

Answer (score 1):

The type of scale should, I believe, mainly influence the distance measure that you use. All clustering methods will need a distance measure. The type of clustering depends on several things, including sample size and what you are trying to find out and what you know already and whether this is a "one off" (in which case, a long processing time might not be a problem) or needs to be done all the time.

Comment: Thanks Peter, my aim is to find clusters of people inside a sample of 3K answers. I am thinking in normalizing this data to a min max transforming it from (1-7) to (0-1) and do so. But my concern is that, as likert data is a continuous and ordinal data if the result of this clusters (if they exists) are relevant. Otherwise I am thinking about using random forests to classify the results. So, that is my dilemma right now. Will I have a meaningful and mathematically explainable classes of people with clustering likert data. Or should I go for Forests ?

Comment: Still awaiting your answer Peter.